# ASP.NET MVC Default Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

Pessoal tenho uma aplicação em ASP.NET MVC com `FormsAutentication` e estou tendo dificuldade em deixar um *controller* como página inicial. Já liberei no `web.config`, mas ainda não funciona. O *controller* se chama site, veja o código:

```
<location path="Site">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Se eu digitar o endereço completo como `teste.com.br/Site` funciona, mas se digitar só `teste.com.br` sempre sou direcionado para página de login.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Permissao/Login" protection="All" slidingExpiration="false" timeout="60" cookieless="UseCookies"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

No meu `routeConfig.cs` está assim:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Site", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Mas sempre é direcionado para página de login ao invés de Site, se eu por o *controller* `Site` como Start page na propriedade do projeto funciona, mas no server de hospedagem não, ou seja, só funciona se configurar na propriedade do projeto, parece que é ignorado todo o resto da configuração do `web.config`, route e etc... Alguém pode dar uma mão?

Comment: Seu *Controller* é decorado com um `[Authorize]`?

Comment: No controller "Site" coloquei [AllowAnonymous], o estranho é que se eu por o controller como start page do projeto funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você configurou seu projeto para que nenhum *Controller* esteja acessível para quem não estiver logado:

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

Remova estas linhas do seu `web.config`.

Adicionalmente, decore os *Controllers* que devem exigir login com:

```
[Authorize]
public class MeuController : Controller { ... }
```

Comment: Valeu Cigano, era isso mesmo, Obrigado!